# Manga with a character named Katana who hunted monsters

Tags: story-identification, manga

Long Time ago I found a manga about a human like weapon named katana that hunted bad guys and other "monsters" like "him" I think, I can't find it and I don't remember much of the plot, but I think it was a little violent, kind of gore.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When was "long ago?"  Check out the other [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/101407) for asking good questions, and see if they help you recall any additional details you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: Is this Katanagatari? But it will be better if you can provide little more details